# Create an alias for a builtin aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am using Postgres for local testing of a hosted database. The hosted database has a couple of functions that do not exist in Postgres. I don't need to replicate these functions, but I need to be able to call the functions with the same name and get a reasonable answer. For example, I would like to alias the count function to approximate_count_distinct. An example query would be:

```
     select approximate_count_distinct(id)
     from table;
```

The behavior of this query would be exactly the same as count. I don't need to worry about the fact it's not exactly the same as on the hosted db

I have looked into CREATE AGGREGATE but can't get the arguments correct. Here is what i was trying to do for CREATE AGGREGATE:

```
   CREATE AGGREGATE approximate_count_distinct(*) 
   ( 
     sfunc = count, 
     stype = bigint, 
     initcond = 0 
   );
```

but it wasn't compiling because it says 
`ERROR: function count(bigint) does not exist`

I tried to find the right way to declare this function but got hopelessly lost. I looked in pg_proc but count seemed to be defined in a weird way as aggregate_dummy as the src symlink.

I looked into `ALIAS FOR` but that doesn't seem to work functions.

Long story short i don't know what to do to make it work. There surely must be an easy way to do this?

Comment: What is the problem? doing a function or make the function return the proper result?

Comment: creating a function.. here is what i was trying to do for CREATE AGGREGATE but it wasnt compiling because it says `ERROR:  function count(bigint) does not exist` here is the code `CREATE AGGREGATE approximate_count_distinct(*)
(
    sfunc = count,
    stype =  bigint,
    initcond = 0
);` . p.s. i tried to find the right way to declare this function but got hopelessly lost. I looked in pg_proc but count seemed to be defined in a weird way as aggregate_dummy as the src symlink. Long story short i dont know what to do to make it work

Comment: post that as part of your question, in a well format every one can understand ;)

Comment: updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the declaration of `count(*)` aggregate, just change the name:

```
create aggregate approximate_count_distinct(*) (
    sfunc = int8inc,
    stype = int8,
    initcond = '0'
);

select count(*), approximate_count_distinct(*)
from generate_series(1, 100)

 count | approximate_count_distinct 
-------+----------------------------
   100 |                        100
(1 row)
```

---

You can use the pseudotype `anyelement` as a generic type of argument:

```
create aggregate approximate_count_distinct(anyelement) (
    sfunc = int8inc_any,
    stype = int8,
    initcond = '0'
);

select 
    approximate_count_distinct(id::int) as int,  
    approximate_count_distinct(id::dec) as dec,
    approximate_count_distinct(id::text) as text
from generate_series(1, 100) id

 int | dec | text 
-----+-----+------
 100 | 100 |  100
(1 row)
```

Comment: great thanks! I think i figured out how to do this for a more generic datatype `create aggregate approximate_count_distinct(varchar) (
    sfunc = int8inc_any,
    stype = int8,
    initcond = '0'
);`

Comment: See the modified answer.